# How to change the string data to Laravel Query format

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am working on a project using Laravel 5.2. I have a search and CSV export functions. I want to export the latest search result as a CSV file if I click on CSV export link.

My logic is :
I pass the search result to front-end (index.blade.php) and store the value in a hidden input field and when I click CSV export link, I will pass this hidden input to the CSV export controller and do the printing operation.

My problem is: how can I change these data format(the hidden input data)

```
[
  {
    "memberId": 9,
    "area_id": 2,
    "status_id": 0,
    "reference_id": 0,
    "productname": null,
    "picaluminum": null,
    "companyName": "てすと",
    "name": "てすと会社",
    "job": 3,
    "relationJob": null,
    "subJobCategory": null,
    "busyo": null,
    "eMail": "y_ikegami@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "zip1": "530",
    "zip2": "0001",
    "pref": 27,
    "prefStr": "大阪府",
    "address1": "大阪市北区梅田2-2-2",
    "address2": "20F",
    "tel1": "06",
    "tel2": "1111",
    "tel3": "1111",
    "fax1": "06",
    "fax2": "9999",
    "fax3": "9999",
    "siteUrl": "http://www.google/",
    "medium": "|1|",
    "pdf": "|1|",
    "created_at": "2015-07-27 18:23:28",
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "memberId": 5275,
    "area_id": 2,
    "status_id": 3,
    "reference_id": 4,
    "productname": "yonascare",
    "picaluminum": "",
    "companyName": "ddd",
    "name": "Test Queserser",
    "job": null,
    "relationJob": null,
    "subJobCategory": null,
    "busyo": null,
    "eMail": null,
    "password": null,
    "zip1": null,
    "zip2": null,
    "pref": null,
    "prefStr": null,
    "address1": "zzzzzz",
    "address2": null,
    "tel1": null,
    "tel2": null,
    "tel3": null,
    "fax1": null,
    "fax2": null,
    "fax3": null,
    "siteUrl": null,
    "medium": null,
    "pdf": null,
    "created_at": "2018-07-06 06:42:20",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-06 06:42:20"
  },
  {
    "memberId": 5279,
    "area_id": 2,
    "status_id": 1,
    "reference_id": 1,
    "productname": "yonascare",
    "picaluminum": "hello",
    "companyName": "yonas3",
    "name": "Test Queserser",
    "job": null,
    "relationJob": 1,
    "subJobCategory": 6,
    "busyo": null,
    "eMail": null,
    "password": null,
    "zip1": null,
    "zip2": null,
    "pref": null,
    "prefStr": null,
    "address1": "zzzzzz",
    "address2": null,
    "tel1": null,
    "tel2": null,
    "tel3": null,
    "fax1": null,
    "fax2": null,
    "fax3": null,
    "siteUrl": null,
    "medium": null,
    "pdf": null,
    "created_at": "2018-07-06 06:57:12",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-06 07:04:51"
  }
]
```

To the following data format (Laravel Query format)

```
Collection {#403 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => MemberMaster {#399 ▼
      #table: "memberMasternewdata"
      #primaryKey: "memberId"
      #fillable: array:10 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:31 [▼
        "memberId" => 9
        "area_id" => 2
        "status_id" => 0
        "reference_id" => 0
        "productname" => null
        "picaluminum" => null
        "companyName" => "てすと"
        "name" => "てすと会社"
        "job" => 3
        "relationJob" => null
        "subJobCategory" => null
        "busyo" => null
        "eMail" => "y_ikegami@gmail.com"
        "password" => "password"
        "zip1" => "530"
        "zip2" => "0001"
        "pref" => 27
        "prefStr" => "大阪府"
        "address1" => "大阪市北区梅田2-2-2"
        "address2" => "20F"
        "tel1" => "06"
        "tel2" => "1111"
        "tel3" => "1111"
        "fax1" => "06"
        "fax2" => "9999"
        "fax3" => "9999"
        "siteUrl" => "http://www.google.com/"
        "medium" => "|1|"
        "pdf" => "|1|"
        "created_at" => "2015-07-27 18:23:28"
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:31 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => MemberMaster {#400 ▶}
    2 => MemberMaster {#401 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What method that actually you used to export to csv? Any packages or libraries? Actually still don't get why you need to transform the json to eloquent model.

Comment: Do you get you search result data from the database? Perhaps you should consider exporting them via a package like https://packalyst.com/packages/package/maatwebsite/excel

Comment: @Dharma I use League CSV https://csv.thephpleague.com/8.0/.

Comment: @Yoong yes, I tried to use maatwebsite. I need to use version 2.1 for my project. But I got the error during installation "Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned," This problem is fixed for version 3.0. But I can't use it for my project as my laravel version is 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'deserialize'.

You could use a package like https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer which you can supply your json data to, and deserialize it into the class you require. or..

First of all the data in your form is JSON. You will need to decode it into an object or an array by calling

```
json_decode($yourData);
```

Once this is decoded you will have an object containing your data.

You need to transform this into your object e.g.

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonData);
$memberMaster = new MemberMaster();
$memberMaster->memberId = $jsonObject->memberId;
```

And continue until you've built the object.

To then turn this into a collection you can call Laravels collection helper

```
$memberMasterCollection = collect([$memberMaster]);
```

This obviously can be more optimal but it gives you the basics.

OR

You could keep it really simple. Instead of the whole object just pass though the ID to your form.

Then just post your id up with the form.

Use a database call to get your object from the DB.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I used the first approach. But I couldn't be successful. But the second approach works for me and it is a better approach for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can convert your Collection to json ecncoded string bys using `json_encode($collection)` function.